# How to use Alias as well as Redirect together on same url

Tags: python, django, apache2, amazon-web-services

I have two projects on same IP. I want `/www/site/fortis/` served by `/projects/fortis` and `/www/site/myfood/` served by `/projects/myfood`, but I am not using `DocumentRoot`. My code is:

```
Alias /myfood /opt/bitnami/projects/myfood/
<Directory  /opt/bitnami/projects/myfood/>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>


Alias /fortis /opt/bitnami/projects/fortis_django/
<Directory  /opt/bitnami/projects/fortis_django/>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
Redirect /fortis/login/

RedirectMatch /fortis  /fortis/login/
RedirectMatch /myfood  /myfood/index/
```

How can I achieve both together?

Answer (score 0):

For the more complex tasks like this, I always find myself falling back to [`mod_rewrite.`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)  I don't have a setup at hand where I can pull together a config for you, but it would be something along the lines of:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule   ^/projects/fortis/(.*)  /www/site/fortis/$1  [NC,R,N]
RewriteRule   ^/projects/myfood/(.*)  /www/site/myfood/$1  [NC,R]
```

I'm sure you'll need to tweak that to match, but `mod_rewrite` gives you much more control -- hopefully it's enough.